# How can I setup an online email contact group?

Tags: google-groups, mailing-list

I would like to set-up an email address like AllStarsFootballTeam@Whatever.com, so that all the members of the All Stars Football team can use that email address instead of the individual players' email addresses each time someone wanted to send a group email out.

Is there a website that does this?

Answer (score 1):

Hundreds.

Two of the biggest:

- [Yahoo! Groups](http://groups.yahoo.com)
- [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com)

But there are many, many more out there. A web search for "mailing list host" should provide other options.