# Create group email to forward mails to list of addresses

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding, mailing-list

I am looking for a way to set up group email for my class. This email address will be used to send mails to all class members.

I've tried creating a Gmail account and forwarding mails to a list of students but looks like Gmail allows forwarding to only two addresses at a time.

How can I create a group email such that any mail to that address will be distributed to all the students in class?

Comment: Closely related (if not duplicates): [How can I setup an online email contact group?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/21483) and [Gmail, how to forward email to group using a filter](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/36848)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Groups is probably your best bet. These two links should be the most helpful for how it sounds like you'll be using it:

- [Overview of the benefits of the Google Groups mailing list](http://support.google.com/groups/answer/46611?hl=en)
- [Create a group](http://support.google.com/groups/answer/2464926)

Based on your description, you'll probably want to set it up so that all members can post to the group.

Comment: Check out my answer to a similar (but different) question: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/58512/41910

Answer (score -1):

I think that the most convenient way to create such mail group is visiting Mail4Group.Com.
This is a free shared mailbox designed especially for student groups.

Comment: Are you affiliated with Mail4Group.com? If so, you should disclose it.